# Differentiate blocks of code based on class without instanceof

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, instanceof

So I have the following inteface `I` which is implemented by classes `A` and `B`:

```
interface I { ... }
class A implements I { ... }
class B implements I { ... }
```

Then I have another interface `OverrideMe` whose method has an object `I` as parameter, and a class that overrides that method and behaves differently depending on the actual class of that parameter:

```
interface OverrideMe {
   void method(I parameter)
}

class Overriding implements OverrideMe {
   @Override
   void method(I parameter) {
      if (I instanceof A) {
         // Code block for A
      }
      else if (I instanceof B) {
         // Code block for B
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a way differentiate both blocks of code by type and without using `instanceof`? I am not sure if this could be done using inheritance.

Keep in mind that I have no control on `I`, `A`, `B` and , I have to use them as they are.

Comment: Why don't you want to do this?

Comment: If you want to call a method that both A and B implement, you don't need that differentiation, the dynamic method lookup will solve that problem. If you want to call a method that, for instance, only B implements, then of course you need to do it (but just for B).

Comment: I don't want to do this because apparently "...is better to avoid using the instanceof operator in a series of if/else statements to differentiate blocks of code based on type, if these types are related by inheritance, it is cleaner to just define a method in the base class, and use overridden methods in these classes...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can depending on what you want to do inside the code block. If you are looking for operating some b-logic on the instance of A or B. You can provide a method declaration inside the interface I and provide the implementation inside class A and B. Example,

```
interface I { 
   void doSomething();
 }
class A implements I {
   void doSomething(){
    //do something here 
} 
 }
class B implements I { 

   void doSomething(){
    //do something here 
} 
 }

interface OverrideMe {
   void method(I parameter)
}

class Overriding implements OverrideMe {
   @Override
   void method(I parameter) {
       parameter.doSomething();
   }
}
```

If aforementioned is not the case, you might have to use `instanceof`

Comment: Thanks Raunak, your solution indeed works and makes sense, my problem is that I have no control over I, A or B, so I cannot add methods to them.